# How to change the default colors in plotly chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating a plotly stacked bar chart and depending on the filters my dataset changes.

The dataset look like:

```
tabNew <- structure(list(Group = c("2016-11", "2016-12", "2017-01", "2017-
02", "2017-03"),
`Did Not Meet Expectations` = c(3, 0.8, 1.5, 0.8, 1.7), 
`Exceeded Expectations` = c(45, 50.6, 32.3, 49.5, 55.6), 
`Met Expectations` = c(51.2, 48.5, 66.2, 49.5, 42.4), 
Unacceptable = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2)),                                                                                               
.Names = c("Group", "Did Not Meet Expectations",
"Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Unacceptable"),                                                                                                                                     
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code to plot the chart is as below:

```
x <- list(
  title = "Time"
)
y <- list(
  title = "Percent"
)

p <- plot_ly(tabNew, x = ~Group, y = ~`Unacceptable`, colors = c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue"),  
             name = 'Unacceptable', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~`Did Not Meet Expectations`, name = 'Did Not Meet Expectations') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~`Met Expectations`, name = 'Met Expectations') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~`Exceeded Expectations`, name = 'Exceeded Expectations') %>%
  layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

The chart looks like:

[image]

This dataset is an example where the `Group` represent `Months`. Sometimes based on filters, the `Group` can represents `Quarters` and in such cases, there may not be all other columns. So there are chances that we have only `Did Not Meet Expectations`, `Exceeded Expectations` and `Met Expectations`.

In either case, I do not want the default colors. I want `Unacceptable` if its there to be shown by `Red`, `Did Not Meet Expectations` if available to be shown as `Yellow` and likewise `Met Expectations` by `Blue` and `Exceeded Expectations` as `Green`. Is there a way to specify this order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
require(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  Group        = c("2016-11", "2016-12", "2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03"),
  DidNot       = c(3, 0.8, 1.5, 0.8, 1.7),
  Exceeded     = c(45, 50.6, 32.3, 49.5, 55.6),
  Met          = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2),
  Unacceptable = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2)
  )

plot_ly(df, x = ~Group) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Exceeded, 
            name = "Exceeded Expectations", 
            type = "scatter", 
            mode = "lines",
            line = list(color = "green")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Unacceptable, 
            name = "Unacceptable", 
            type = "scatter", 
            mode = "lines",
            line = list(color = "red")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Percent"))
```

This code produces:

[image]

I modified your dataframe syntax to be neater to me and I obviously did not draw all the lines for you but you get the picture.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. What if the `type` as `bar` instead of `scatter` and `barmode` as `stack`. In that case the `line` argument is invalid. How would you specify the `color` in that case?

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- plot_ly(tabNew, x = ~Group, y = ~`Unacceptable`,
     name = 'Unacceptable', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
     line=list(color="red")) %>%
     add_trace(y = ~`Did Not Meet Expectations`, name = 'Did Not Meet Expectations',
     line=list(color="yellow")) %>%
     add_trace(y = ~`Met Expectations`, name = 'Met Expectations',
     line=list(color="green")) %>%
     add_trace(y = ~`Exceeded Expectations`, name = 'Exceeded Expectations',line=list(color="blue")) %>%
     layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

If you were using the iris dataset

```
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, color = ~Species, , colors=c("Red","Green","Blue"))
```

Comment: I have updated my code - you should be able to recreate the plot. For some reason I get an error when I run your code for both examples.

Comment: The `iris` example just has an extra `,`. It works otherwise.

Comment: The code for my dataset does not work. I get the error - `Error: Variables must be length 1 or 5.
Problem variables: 'color'`

Comment: Thanks @user2510479

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to melt the data.frame in long-format and simply map the criterion names to specific colors (see also [Scatter and Line Plots in R](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/)):

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr) ## to melt data.frame

## create long-format data.frame
df <- data.frame(
        Group        = c("2016-11", "2016-12", "2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03"),
        DidNot       = c(3, 0.8, 1.5, 0.8, 1.7),
        Exceeded     = c(45, 50.6, 32.3, 49.5, 55.6),
        Met          = c(51.2, 48.5, 66.2, 49.5, 42.4),
        Unacceptable = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2)
     ) %>%
     gather(key = "criterion", value = "measurement", -Group)

## specify color maps
colors <- c("red", "gold", "blue", "green")
names(colors) <- c("Unacceptable", "DidNot", "Met", "Exceeded")

## create plot
plot_ly(df, x = ~Group) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~measurement, color = ~criterion, colors = colors) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time"), 
         yaxis = list(title = "Percent")
  )
```

This should also work when not all column names are present in the data.frame.